# Dropdown control on Backstage scaffolder (or radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, backstage

I'm creating a template in the Backstage scaffolder and I need a way to present to the user an option selection UI, it can be a dropdown select or a group of radio buttons, something like that:

```
Name of your project ______
Include foo [ ]
CSS Processor |v|
 - None
 - SASS
 - Stylus
```

I couldn't find how to do the select part. The only dropdown that exists in the [documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/writing-templates) is the Repository Picker, but it is a custom control, besides that, I could only find examples for `type: string` and `type: boolean`. Actually, there's something about `type: array`, but the example seems incomplete (or this type is not intended for what I'm looking for)

Is it possible to do without a custom component?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I've managed to solve this by doing

```
  parameters:
    - title: My scaffolder
      properties:
        ...
        includeRequester:
          title: Include an API requester?
          type: string
          description: Should this module include an API requester? (REST or GraphQL)
          default: none
          enum:
            - none
            - rest
            - graphql
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to define labels for the options. Ideally, I had in mind something like

```
none: Don't include a requester
rest: Include a REST requester
graphql: Include a GraphQL requester
```

but it's OK, despite not having labels, it's working as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

From the current [documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/input-examples#array-with-custom-titles) I think your solution would look like this:

```yaml
  parameters:
    - title: My scaffolder
      properties:
        ...
        includeRequester:
          title: Include an API requester?
          type: string
          description: Should this module include an API requester? (REST or GraphQL)
          default: none
          enum:
            - none
            - rest
            - graphql
          enumNames:
            - 'Don't include a requester'
            - 'Include a REST requester'
            - 'Include a GraphQL requester'
```